# exclude include in p6spy not working

Tags: logging, p6spy

I was trying p6spy filter option. I am using p6spy version 2+
I need to exclude logs with select statements.

My properties file is shown below.

```
filter=true
include=
exclude=select [a-z,_, , =, ']*
```

But with this configuration i am not getting the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the *filter=true* tip, saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the include and exclude options are looking for regular strings or phrases (comma separated) and not regular expressions.  If you want to use a regular expression, use the sqlexpression setting instead.

For example, if you want to include select and insert statements, you could just use the include setting as shown below.

```
include=select,insert
```

For the same selection logic using a regular expression, you would use sqlexpression as shown below.

```
sqlexpression=select.*|insert.*
```